# Wrong boolean result comparing Date objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write test that compare some dates. So far i have 2 tests, one of them works as intended, but the other one fails because doesnt/not correctly compare dates.
Here is my code:

```
def self.has_expired?(card, start_month, start_year, annually)
    card_date = Date.new(card.year, card.month, -1)
    billing_date = Date.new(start_year, start_month, -1)
    if !annually
      p '--------'
      p card_date
      p billing_date
      card_date > billing_date

    else
      #return false
    end
  end
```

creditcard object

```
creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :number     => 1234567890123456
        :month      => 01,
        :year       => 13,
        :first_name => 'John', 
        :last_name  => 'Doe',
        :verification_value  => 132,
        :brand => 'visa'
      )
```

Here is output of p's
First block works as intended.

```
"--------"
Tue, 31 Jan 0013
Thu, 28 Feb 2013
false
```

Second block fails, expecting true, but got false

```
."--------"
Tue, 31 Jan 0013
Fri, 30 Nov 2012
false
```

Here is my rspec code

```
describe CreditCard do 
  context 'card_expired' do
    it 'should return false with args passed to method (02month, 13 year, annually==false)' do
      CreditCard.has_expired?(creditcard, 02, 2013, false).should == false
    end

    it 'should return true with args passed to method (11month, 12 year, annually==false)' do
      CreditCard.has_expired?(creditcard, 11, 2012, false).should == true
    end
  end

end
```

in irb it works as charm, returning correct value(true/false)

Comment: weird error. Unrelated, but you can write `unless annually` instead of `if !annually`. Also note that a leading zero is an octal number, so `01` works just like `1`, but if you try `09` you'll get an error.

Comment: why are these octal instead of decimal?

Comment: in ruby, # is a number in base 10, 0# is a number in octal or base 8, and 0x# is a number in hexadecimal or hex or base 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your logic. A card is expired when the expiration date is before the billing date, thus when

```
card_date < billing_date # expired
```

and not when

```
card_date > billing_date # valid
```

---

Also try puting in the full 2013 and see if that helps if it keeps breaking

```
:year => 2013,
```

You're also missing a comma after this line (probably a copy/paste error) `:number     => 1234567890123456`

Comment: comma  was missing because of copypaste, but about logic, i'm not sure. The thing, i'm trying to achieve is to return failse if card exp date earlier then payment date, so i guess my credit card expiration date should be higher then payment date. Even rails console gives true if i compare my dates, but not rspec

Comment: Solved this issue by adding 2013 instead of 13 which ruby converted to 0013

Comment: you should rename the method then, because I always expect boolean methods like `has_expired?` to return `true` if the statement is true. I'd call it `expired?` and return true if its expired, or `valid?` and return false if it has expired, like you do